# suppress page numbers in document's front matter

Tags: page-numbering

I have a problem and I want that someone tell me how I can resolve that. 
I want that the number of page in my report start in the page of introduction but in reality it starts in the didecas and liste of contents. I want that these pages have not number. This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor} %les couleurs
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,1}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[top=2 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
%\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\include{title-content}
\color{black}
\doublespacing
\include{dedicaces-content}
%\include{remerciement}


\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{plain} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction générale}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information regarding the LaTeX document class you use (`report`? `book`? something else?) and whether you use any LaTeX packages that may affect the page style and page numbering style that's in effect. You should certainly try (a) issuing the command `\pagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\begin{document}` and (b) issuing the commands `\pagestyle{plain}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` immediately before `\chapter{Introduction}`. That said, I can't help but remark that it would be a bit unusual not to have any page numbers in the document's front matter area.

Comment: @Mico: have tried what you suggest but the same problem last.

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional pieces if information. You may have to include the instruction `\thispagesttle{empty}` in each of your included .tex files and also have to insert that instruction after the `\tableofcontents` command (and issue a `\clearpage` after the front matter).

Comment: @Mico: thank you for your answer can you put this in my code please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note: I've rewritten this answer after the OP explained more details of the document's setup.)

To suppress page numbering in a part of the document, one has to both set `\pagenumbering{empty}` and take care of commands -- such as `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, and `\listoftables` -- that internally invoke a command (specifically, the `\chapter` command) which (re)sets the page style of the current page to `plain`. In the example below, I use the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package to "patch" the chapter command. To keep the scope of the modification local to the front matter of the document, I've  put a `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` pair around the relevant part of the document. Finally, after the end of the frontmatter, it's necessary to restore `plain` pagenumbering and to restart the page numbering by issuing the command `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. Happy TeXing!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,1}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,pgfplots,filecontents}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

% Load the 'etoolbox' package to provide to
% patch the '\chapter` command (locally, in this case)
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}    % switch to "empty" page style for front matter of document
\begingroup
% In this TeX group, the first page of new "chapters" should obey
% '\thispagestyle{empty}' rather than the default '\thispagestyle{plain}'.
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}

\include{title-content}
\color{black}
\doublespacing
\include{dedicaces-content}
\include{remerciement}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup % end of TeX group

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}      % revert to "plain" page style
\pagenumbering{arabic} % restart page numbering
\chapter{Introduction générale}
% 19 more "dummy" chapters, just to make the ToC span 2 pages
\chapter{Bla 2}
\chapter{Bla 3}
\chapter{Bla 4}
\chapter{Bla 5}
\chapter{Bla 6}
\chapter{Bla 7}
\chapter{Bla 8}
\chapter{Bla 9}
\chapter{Bla 10}
\chapter{Bla 11}
\chapter{Bla 12}
\chapter{Bla 13}
\chapter{Bla 14}
\chapter{Bla 15}
\chapter{Bla 16}
\chapter{Bla 17}
\chapter{Bla 18}
\chapter{Bla 19}
\chapter{Bla 20}
\end{document}
```