# Page number and header

Tags: header-footer, numbering, lyx

I am new with LaTeX code... Few months ago my mentor recommended me LyX and I found it funny to write my thesis on it.

I read some preview questions and did not find what I exactly want.

My issues:

1. I would like that the page number starts at the 6th page.
2. From the 6th page to the 50th page, I wanna add header and footer:

   - header [L] {Analyse du mécanisme de compensation}
   - header [R] a logo located in my document files PATH: `C:\Users\M. Louis\Documents\New Scotia.png`
   - footer[L] {Mozard LOUIS}
   - Footer [R] {Econometrics and Data Science, 2020}

With the orange line on it (see the picture).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also writing a thesis, although in my case the University (UBC) provided a LaTeX template which includes instructions since they want a specific format. Perhaps there is a similar template available from your institution.

Otherwise implementing the specific changes would probably require viewing the template you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fit in LyX Using LaTeX, one can manage:

1. The first six pages are probably frontmatter, e.g. titlepage, table of contents, ..
   My recommendation is to differentiate with \frontmatter and \mainmatter, but you'll find roman page numbers in the frontmatter. To fully suppress page numbering, we have to dig deeper, as e.g. toc reset the pagestyle (and therfore page numbering scheme). How to deal with that has been answered by mico here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61179/suppress-page-numbers-in-documents-front-matter#:~:text=To%20suppress%20page%20numbering%20in,the%20current%20page%20to%20plain%20](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61179/suppress-page-numbers-in-documents-front-matter#:%7E:text=To%20suppress%20page%20numbering%20in,the%20current%20page%20to%20plain%20).
2. 

You'll have to include the package fancyhdr and define you own pagestyle (put this before \begin{document})
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{myheader}{%
\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\fancyhead[L]{Analyse du mécanisme de compensation}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}
\fancyfoot[L]{Mozard LOUIS}
\fancyfoot[R]{Econometrics and Data Science, 2020}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} %centered page number
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% 1pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
\color{orange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}% 1pt footer rule
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\footwidth{%
\color{orange}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
}
then you can use \pagestyle{myheader} wherever you want.

Just found you can edit the LaTeX preamble in Lyx: Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble